# An elementary question about the Krull dimension of modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of modules, we have that $\operatorname{Supp}M=\operatorname{Supp}M'\cup \operatorname{Supp}M''$. Furthermore can we obtain that $\dim M=\dim M'+\dim M''$? In fact, I want to know that given a module $M$ with $\dim M=n$, is it possible to construct an exact sequence as above with $\dim M'=0$ and $\dim M''=n-1$?

Comment: I've heard of the Krull dimension of a ring, but what is the Krull dimension of a module?

Comment: Or did you mean the projective dimension?

Comment: For the second question, dimM' should be 1.

Comment: -1. This is perhaps a research level topic, but not a research level question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of $M$ is the maximum of the dimensions of $M'$ and $M''$, so what you are asking for cannot happen (at least not in the noetherian case). To Dylan: the dimension of a module is the dimension of its support.

Comment: Thanks! Is it called the "Krull dimension" though? That's what confused me... 

Comment: Is there a reference for this result? Thanks!

Comment: $dim(X \cup Y) = max(dim(X),dim(Y))$ is a an easy exercise in general topology.

Comment: To the OP: I think this should be proved in any book that discusses dimensions of modules. In case as Martin says it is a very easy exercise. To Dylan: the dimension of the spectrum of a ring A is the Krull dimension of A, and the definition for modules is a useful generalization. It can also be interpreted as the Krull dimension of the ring modulo the annihilator of the module (I am always referring to finite modules over noetherian rings).

Comment: Does the equality hold when M is not finite?